# Disk Space of Cardano node & Cardano DB-sync

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync, nix

I recently installed the Cardano node and Db-sync and Postgres using nix. I use a server with 97 GB of space, node version 1.34.1 and DB-sync version 12.0.
 The node took about 70 GB after fully synced and DB-sync is still syncing on epoch 254. So far in total they have taken 88 GB of disk space.
My questions are:

1. Is this normal?
2. How much disk space is it expected to take when it is fully synced?
3. Does installing with cabal save up space? and how much?

Thank you for your answer!

**Edit**: For anyone interested, the cexplorer (i.e. mainnet) database at epoch 372 takes 221GB and the cardano-node folder 84GB (with nix installation).
The whole installation (node, db-sync, nix, Postgres) takes 338GB of storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an FYI, the mainnet node DB/chain itself is currently using 41GB of disk on Linux.

```
$du -h db
38G     db/immutable
2.9G    db/ledger
163M    db/volatile
41G     db
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but if I remember correctly the chain (up to epoch 324) took me about 60-70 GB. Definitely more than 41 GB. Can you tell me please where I can find the db folder?

Comment: I found the db folder, mine is named db-mainnet, and you are right. It is indeed 41gb and together with cardano-db-sync folder they are 44 gb. The Postgres cexplorer database is 15 gb. I am sorry for the possibly naïve question, I'm kinda new to cardano and Ubuntu, but where is the rest disk space taken from? Thanks again.

Comment: You can check disk usage with the Linux 'du' command eg 'du -h .' to get output of the current directory and sub-directories. You might have hidden directories too, so the command 'ls -la' will show you all directories, then you and do a 'du' on them eg 'du -h dir1'. If building from source then cabal and nix take up a lot of space.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! I just checked and although the node + db-sync + postgres take up 59 GB, nix alone takes 29 GB! That is extreme. Do you know if it safe to remove nix or will everything collapse? I think I will also make a new post about it.

Comment: Yeah probably best to accept an answer on this one and open a new question with more details. In short though, it will depend on what you want to use that system for.

Answer (score 3):

The database for `db-sync` at chain tip is over 100GB.

> Syncing on epoch 254. So far in total they have taken 88 GB of disk space.

Yep and by the time you get to epoch 323 (current tip) the database will need more than 100GB.

> Is this normal?

Yes

> How much disk space is it expected to take when it is fully synced?

Currently about 100-120 GB.

> Does installing with cabal save up space? and how much?

Might save you as much as 10GB.

Comment: Thank you for answering! So far I'm at 92 GB with DB-sync at epoch 261 and syncing really slowly. 
When you talk about the space needed, you mean for both the node and DB-sync right?
Cabal is definitely not worth re-installing then.

Comment: If you are happy with that answer, please consider accepting and up voting it.

Comment: I cannot upvote yet because I'm new. Despite I appreciate your answer, I would appreciate helping more, since you even took the time to re-comment, instead of reputation begging.

Answer (score 1):

What is the current storage consumption for DB-sync? There's no "extended" version anymore either, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe there is no "extended" anymore. My latest install was through snapshot though and the "extended" parameter was not needed. The "epoch" table was still created. I assume that's the general case and not snapshot specific.

Comment: The cardano-db-sync folder is currently at 29GB (epoch 372).

Answer (score 0):

For Epoch 359, cnode at 82G and db sync is 216G (sudo du -hd 1 /var/lib/postgresql/12). Looking  at the comments above it makes sense that the DB is way larger, 2.6x in this case.